# String Object Representation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

What are the differences between the `__str__()` and `str()` methods in python?

Comment: check this https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html. Look for __str__

Comment: In some sense, `str == operator.methodcaller('__str__')` defines the relationship between the two.

Comment: @Jerrybibo Not quite. `str` is a *type*; `__str__` is an *instance* method.

Comment: good point. @chepner I need to brush up on my terminologies.

Answer (score 2):

`__str__` (usually read dunder, for  double under) is an instance method that is called whenever you run `str(<object>)` and returns the string representation of the object.

`str(foo)` acts as a function trying to convert `foo` into a string.

**Note:**
There is also a `__repr__()` method which is fairly similar to `__str__()`, the main difference being `__repr__` should return an *unambiguous* string and `__str__` is for a *readable* string. For a great response on the diffences between the two I'd suggest giving [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/4225467) a read.

Answer (score 0):

`__str__()` is a magic instance method that doee this: when you print a class instance variable with `print()`, it will give you a string that can be modified by changing the returned string in the `__str__()` method. There's probably a better explanation to it but I can show you with code:

```
class Thing:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def __str__(self):
       return "What do you want?"  #always use return

a = Thing()
print(a)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
What do you want?
```

`str()` just converts a variable into a string type variable.

```
print(str(12.0))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
'12.0'
```

You can confirm it is a string using the `type()` function.

```
print(type(str(12.)))
```

I don't know the exact output of that but it will peobably have `'str'` in it.